# Spring boot: @Scheduler that updates cron espression without restarting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

I Need to schedule a task on Spring Boot that reads a cron espression from the database. I did this using the @Scheduled annotation and reading a property inside a database, but my client is asking to be able to update the cron expression in the database and having it affect the scheduled without restarting the application. I know this isnt possible with the @Scheduled annotation, but would It be possible to schedule another task that extracts the cron expression every hour, and then feed the updated expression to the actual scheduled that executes the task? Basically updating the variable that Is Fed to the second scheduled. If this isnt possible, do you know any alternative ways to achieve this without using the @Scheduled annotation? Thank you.

Comment: Does the dynamic scheduler need to use a cron or is a simple updatable  frequency ok?

Comment: It needs a cron. I solved this using SchedulingConfigurer class.

Comment: How about posting the solution as an answer and accepting it? This is a problem others will have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using SchedulingConfigurer, here's a sample:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

  

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                //run your code here
            }
        }, new Trigger() {
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
             //extract cron from database

                

                CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(new CronTrigger(//insert cron that you got from database));
                return trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that nextExecutionDate will only run at the next expected time. So if you were to change your cron from (for example) monthly to daily, you code would only pick up the change on the next month.  If you are only expecting changes to minutes or seconds then this is not so relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing this using your own Runnable and a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) Which starts a thread to do what you are asking once every hour.

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void chronJob Runner() {
     final Runnable chronJobWorker = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { //Request logic }
     };
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 1, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Not sure if this is the best way of doing it, but is certainly one possible way of completing this task at a scheduled rate.